# How to check what type of resources a server is running out of?

Tags: bash, system, monitoring

It is quite possible to research specific Linux/Ubuntu/Bash error messages (for example 'Cannot fork') and see what type of resource the server may be running out of.

However, this question is to specifically ask if there are any tools, or scripts, or methods, to quickly check ALL resources of a server (i.e. `ulimit -a`, `/etc/security/limits.conf`, `/etc/sysctl.conf`, `/etc/security/limits.d/*`, etc.) and what the current consumption of the same is.

Perhaps a system monitoring tool of some form.

In other words, I am looking for a tool, something similar to how visual `htop` is, which shows where a server is at in terms of resource consumption.

Extra brownie points if such a tool, or similar, would be able to show if some limits are oversized. I have noticed before that if you set certain limits too high, even without there being anything amiss on the server otherwise, the server can run into issues during high load.